# Too many if/else statements in converting user inputs to types in C++

Tags: c++, command-line-interface, c++17

I have a template class with 3 template arguments.

```
template <class T, class U, class Y>
class MyClass {};
```

I wanna get input from users by CLI arguments, something like `./cli float driver-x load`

- The first arg can be `float` or `double`
- The second arg is a driver name: `driver-x`, `driver-y`, ...
- The third argument is about the action type: `load`, `unload`, ...

If I want to create a new instance of `MyClass` based on user inputs, I have to define many `if/else` statements. Because a user inputs are `string` and I have to prepare a condition on them.
So, it will be something like this:

```
if (data_type == "float")
    if (driver == "driver-x")
        if (action == "load")
            MyClass<float, DriverX, Load> t;
            t......
```

As far as I know, it's impossible to store a type in a variable in C++.

So, is there any way exists to improve the `if/else` statements? Something like:

```
if (data_type == "float")
    //

if (driver == "driver-x")
   //

if (action == "load")
   //

MyClass<......> t;
t.....;
```

Or any other way?

I'm looking for a way to improve these `if/else` statements.

Comment: I would recommend using command line parser library. I use CLI11, but there is a variety to choose from. As for your question, you can try to build a state machine on paper and try to reduce it, but it will be brittle to changes and perhaps even less readable.

Comment: I'm using command line parser, it's cxxopts.

Comment: I have a question about the design: can those different pieces if functionality be somehow combined into a type? The problem with templates depending on run time arguments is that you can only pass input, receiving any correctly typed output is not possible without some sort of variant type. Perhaps you could write a function that defines possible combinations (if there are few), then return variant or throw if the combination is illegal. Test could be done by concatenating the values while skipping the unconstrained ones.

Comment: @Incomputable would you please take an example about combining types?

Comment: you could implement your templated type as non templated by depending on three values `double` for first arg because it can be used for both, an enum or some other constraining type for the second arg, and a function pointer/lambda for the last one. That way, you will still have the same amount of configuration, it will just have more runtime nature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build some machinery to do this for you, extracting it into a function call.

For example, here I build a tuple which contains strings and types, then I check a passed string against all of them:

```cpp
#include <string_view>
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct mapped_type {
    const std::string_view key;
    using type = T;

    explicit constexpr operator bool() const noexcept {
        return true;
    }
};

namespace detail {
    template<class K, class F, class M, std::size_t I>
    constexpr void lookup_impl(const K& key, F&& f, M&& m, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>) {
        using tuple_t = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<M>::type>::type;
        if constexpr (I < std::tuple_size<tuple_t>::value) {
            const auto& mapping = std::get<I>(m);
            if (mapping.key == key) {
                std::forward<F>(f)(mapping);
                return;
            }
            lookup_impl(key, std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<M>(m), std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I + 1>{});

        } else {
            std::forward<F>(f)(std::false_type{});
        }
    }
}

// Calls `f` with the first value from `m` that matches the key
// or `std::false_type{}` if no key matches.
template<class K, class F, class M>
constexpr void lookup(const K& key, F&& f, M&& m) {
    detail::lookup_impl(key, std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<M>(m), std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>{});
}

// This is our mapping for the first argument
inline constexpr auto data_type_map = std::make_tuple(
    mapped_type<float>{ "float" },
    mapped_type<double>{ "double" }
);

// Example usage
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const char* s = "float";

    lookup(s, [](const auto& arg) {
        if constexpr (!arg) {
            std::cout << "Invalid type\n";
        } else {
            using type = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(arg)>::type>::type::type;
            std::cout << "Got type: " << typeid(type).name() << '\n';
        }
    }, data_type_map);
}
```

And then you can call this recursively inside the lambda.

You could also create a version that takes a tuple of keys and a tuple of values to call one function with many arguments:

```cpp
#include <string_view>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct mapped_type {
    const std::string_view key;
    using type = T;

    explicit constexpr operator bool() const noexcept {
        return true;
    }
};

namespace detail {
    template<class K, class F, class M, std::size_t I>
    constexpr void lookup_impl(F&& f, const K& key, M&& m, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>) {
        using tuple_t = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<M>::type>::type;
        if constexpr (I < std::tuple_size<tuple_t>::value) {
            const auto& mapping = std::get<I>(m);
            if (mapping.key == key) {
                std::forward<F>(f)(mapping);
                return;
            }
            lookup_impl(std::forward<F>(f), key, std::forward<M>(m), std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I + 1>{});
        } else {
            std::forward<F>(f)(std::false_type{});
        }
    }

    template<class F, class K, class M, std::size_t I>
    constexpr void multilookup_impl(F&& f, const K& keys, M&& mappings, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>) {
        constexpr std::size_t size = std::tuple_size<typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<K>::type>::type>::value;
        if constexpr (I >= size) {
            std::forward<F>(f)();
        } else {
            lookup_impl([&](const auto& current_lookup) {
                multilookup_impl(
                    [&](const auto&... args) { std::forward<F>(f)(current_lookup, args...); },
                    keys, mappings, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I + 1>{}
                );
            }, std::get<I>(keys), std::get<I>(mappings), std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>{});
        }
    }
}

template<class F, class K, class M>
constexpr void lookup(F&& f, const K& keys, M&& mappings) {
    using map_tuple_t = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<M>::type>::type;
    using key_tuple_t = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<K>::type>::type;
    constexpr std::size_t size = std::tuple_size<key_tuple_t>::value;
    static_assert(size == std::tuple_size<map_tuple_t>::value, "Wrong number of keys for given number of maps");
    detail::multilookup_impl(std::forward<F>(f), keys, mappings, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>{});
}
```

Which looks almost the same, but there's one more level of calls.

It would be used like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>


inline constexpr auto data_type_map = std::make_tuple(
    mapped_type<float>{ "float" },
    mapped_type<double>{ "double" }
);

inline constexpr auto driver_type_map = std::make_tuple(
    mapped_type<DriverX>{ "driver-x" },
    mapped_type<DriverY>{ "driver-y" }
);

inline constexpr auto action_type_map = std::make_tuple(
    mapped_type<Load>{ "load" },
    mapped_type<Unload>{ "unload" }
);

int main() {
    const char* a = "float";
    const char* b = "driver-x";
    const char* c = "load";

    lookup([](const auto& data, const auto& driver, const auto& action) {
        if constexpr (!data) {
            std::cout << "Could not parse data!\n";
        } else if constexpr (!driver) {
            std::cout << "Could not parse driver!\n";
        } else if constexpr (!action) {
            std::cout << "Could not parse action!\n";
        } else {
            using data_type = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(data)>::type>::type::type;
            using driver_type = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(driver)>::type>::type::type;
            using action_type = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(action)>::type>::type::type;

            MyClass<data_type, driver_type, action_type> t;
            std::cout << "Constructed a " << typeid(decltype(t)).name() << '\n';
        }
    },
        std::array<const char*, 3>{ a, b, c },
        std::forward_as_tuple(data_type_map, driver_type_map, action_type_map)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's my take

```
template<typename T>
struct proxy { // or std::type_identity
    using type = T;
};
template<typename... Ts>
using choice_of = std::variant<proxy<Ts>...>;

template<typename T, typename>
using type_const_t = T;

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
std::optional<choice_of<T, Ts...>> choose(std::string const &choice, std::string const &head, type_const_t<std::string const&, Ts>... tail) noexcept {
    if(choice == head) return proxy<T>{};
    else if constexpr(sizeof...(Ts) == 0) return std::nullopt;
    else if(auto rec = choose<Ts...>(choice, tail...)) return std::visit(
        [](auto rec) -> choice_of<T, Ts...> { return rec; },
        *rec); 
    else return std::nullopt;
}

auto data_choice = choose<float, double>(data_type, "float", "double");
auto driver_choice = choose<DriverX, DriverY>(driver, "driver-x", "driver-y");
auto action_choice = choose<Load, Unload>(action, "load", "unload");
std::visit([](auto data_type_p, auto driver_p, auto action_p) {
    auto t = MyClass<typename decltype(data_type_p)::type, typename decltype(driver_p)::type, typename decltype(action_p)::type>{};
    // do stuff with t
}, data_choice.value(), driver_choice.value(), action_choice.value());
```

[Complete example on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEAFYAbKS3oAMnlqYAcsYBGmYubOkADqgWE6rR6hibmVn4BanT2ji5G7p5m3koq0bQMBMzEBCHGppaKypiqQZnZBLHObh5eilk5eWGFCg2VDtUJtckAlIqoBsTIHADkUgDMDsiGWADU4uM66kYieD4L2OIADACCE1MzmPOL6q3EmMxGG9t7kpO00wZzC3o%2B6WzXu/sPh8c6CmcLldxpsvncDk8ji9WlgAB7DN6fW73R7PRYAN2yeBEBCRNwImCMPmEBJeBAAnj4tJcjgAVJFnAyqWY%2BYioWHk%2BYAdmkswA9HzZiRZjCQCAKVSAPp4LD0Qjkm6zJWzAwBUSzCVQ8YAEVm9PGsi%2BXO1C0NOwJRJJmDJlOpRkwADonXqFEjVQ5gLNkAhUHhhpLUFRjrrRSBMcRsfQXqz2QrFrTXSCnQ7rgabvjCcTmKTFpraDS9aQNbb8/a3WrPZrJWhaK1JQRg3rTendhaszmdHmC7Si137cmXQyCOgxag3kEPotvb7/YGXj2XcnU9gvT7/JgIKGzh6vXRWvNJBZp37MEWtwQI%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%2BMWbHCcQx6IIbOgjkDEKTwUEAceJxYypHEBycpzBqa2vKUbR2Y1I0iaIwJRs3NkQ83K8mGf1rBtb2QPieQRpG%2BZ0HGi0ZrH%2BbJimqZQiXeQok1JbRiA5cIDdLr6WZLOqqWCHG1AJoFsV0FQFYHElDw2WIabBaMVB0Q3DGegdM4ICsr3XNqmqTTqnZGWZbUIzj4gAA1rsolLc4bfO8ELgBNUv7d5CvZlsVBsPr/Km4AVVoGS28hsuzVDfwLyBBaxw8bMSDNnQo9HOGjDHosq8LkvGNvXX4pExLfOnnHl48Iv%2B5NSRJHyu2biH%2Bex6pYhJ%2BIafZ5AYfznh29UCXguPDrtfDw3gGxKFIbPen9iA1yPoTM%2BGdL4j1foecet8iD33posR%2Bz9R5vyLC3NuP8LB/wSgAneyCjaEywegcBJ9IFZxznZNBsCLDwLvg/aBL8F4YNmN3Xu6Bdya3XnBf%2BhFCE6AZifDhrcyHkUohQlK596qWmzNaXMJZuxtTtEcNKO1VGzD2CCMqxAmQNgALLkh0MIAE11Cp6lmLCNOSpdRkIdkqVGzBqrnxRm2Rqij2r2kLBolqsx1F9iONo0E1DBa0NYXAm%2BjCiGoKvmwoxJjmAAleuo4J3CbyHiMBvG6%2BCBFAMJgk0xrpyInyAUYB0sJ8knxNqU3e5SuG70JjUomdSHTMCqafSRp8UYyJ2A4BsIdaAp3MajZU6tPToGzMwestpFYnyoL3XE1TZjoBAXMyQqzq4eACgqMwQi9lNOlqUOg6zOEQIcdLHyKypnViWlqXUI0wo%2B0mi8BZrcCBFiDgYVw7ANgQEmVkGZVJmlvOzIcwmXyfnWhPjbG6MtfKbMLrc0KT1UDrjGi8xY%2B9i4fy2aAv5iKPDNMJcQAK1jlkQpATswmsKLHwqOekZFJ5UXoueX7F4pCiyiOwn85gxzaDNLORSk%2BBge5iJpTYgO9lHJK1VndBFNyqw%2BCLPSklkplWXI0nyxlPhskWIQvSrWOpZiFKSYmTsSjvFYGmJqf5irny6rFJqFRfjrWsFtWqx14pbQuoLG6212qgjqp6E620ZFpDeHribCRJoB5Q2VAKFZvlWhIyDBNQgCANTxqVKGNA6kgFGqEfzCBezaDnNBkqO2nybmfRWSAply0GVBt6rSzOIw%2BisBACMMwIxSCmBGFsXtqAu1CJkHIEUAwhhQjuJwXtBAu2DqsqQAA1uYAAnA6NdyQ108C5BYAAHMkSQZhxhCC7dwXt/bB2kGHSMXt3MtikHnQO9tpA4CwCQFBEoPkyAUFUsQYACgAAKIhlAMB9BNfts7SBoCJCBbMQQQOOFYOBv2V7e2wZ8CBWo0wRDAE4FsQjMHg5YfYMQAA8upVDkGF29q/cgHYAHuZ3usLCEomR8D9t7TQegTA2AcB4PwQQwhRAoDkHIIQeBXDc0gH0WSQRmMBRhBhCQY6ZCcC5PeydwxBAwgcEhsDEGoOvs7d2y9tGb1dthPuiwAULDcC9CJz0BGHRbFc7MbAbHkA/tmBAXAhBhQTE4GBUdytpBzto0u1d3A3NbG4DFw9M74tcm4FyM9IwL19os7e%2B9IBH3PsXR2rtkhzMvssyxgr7a%2BiFwCBobgQA%3D)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like X-macros:

```
    #define YOUR_TABLE \
    X(float, DriverX, "driver-x", Load) \
    X(int, DriverY, "driver-y", action2) \
    X(int, DriverY, "driver-y", action3)

    #define X(data_type, driver, driverName, action) if((0 == strcmp(#data_type,argv[1])) \
    && (0 == strcmp(driverName,argv[2])) && (0 == strcmp(#action,argv[3])))\
    { \
       MyClass<data_type, driver, action> t; \
       t.... \
    }
    YOUR_TABLE 
    #undef X
```

Answer (score 2):

Prepare your puke-bag, here is a *far-from-elegant* solution but
simple enough to be easily adapted.
The main drawback I see is that all the remaining of the application
that needs to work with the created instance must stand in a
lambda-closure (this solution does not *return* this instance).

Every possible argument is considered only once in a
dedicated function (not X times Y times Z if/else).

```
/**
  g++ -std=c++17 -o prog_cpp prog_cpp.cpp \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct DriverX { auto show() const { return "DriverX"; } };
struct DriverY { auto show() const { return "DriverY"; } };
struct Load    { auto show() const { return "Load";    } };
struct Unload  { auto show() const { return "UnLoad";  } };

template<typename RealType,
         typename DriverType,
         typename ActionType>
struct MyClass
{
  RealType real{};
  DriverType driver{};
  ActionType action{};
  auto show() const
  {
    return std::to_string(sizeof(real))+" bytes real, "+
           driver.show()+", "+action.show();
  }
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<typename RealType,
         typename DriverType,
         typename DoEverythingFunction>
void
with_MyClass_3(const std::string &action,
               DoEverythingFunction fnct)
{
  if(action=="load")
  {
    return fnct(MyClass<RealType, DriverType, Load>{});
  }
  if(action=="unload")
  {
    return fnct(MyClass<RealType, DriverType, Unload>{});
  }
  throw std::runtime_error{"unexpected action: "+action};
}

template<typename RealType,
         typename DoEverythingFunction>
void
with_MyClass_2(const std::string &driver,
               const std::string &action,
               DoEverythingFunction fnct)
{
  if(driver=="driver-x")
  {
    return with_MyClass_3<RealType, DriverX>(action, fnct);
  }
  if(driver=="driver-y")
  {
    return with_MyClass_3<RealType, DriverY>(action, fnct);
  }
  throw std::runtime_error{"unexpected driver: "+driver};
}

template<typename DoEverythingFunction>
void
with_MyClass(const std::string &real,
             const std::string &driver,
             const std::string &action,
             DoEverythingFunction fnct)
{
  if(real=="float")
  {
    return with_MyClass_2<float>(driver, action, fnct);
  }
  if(real=="double")
  {
    return with_MyClass_2<double>(driver, action, fnct);
  }
  throw std::runtime_error{"unexpected real: "+real};
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int
main(int argc,
     char **argv)
{
  std::cout << "~~~~ hardcoded types ~~~~\n";
  const MyClass<float, DriverX, Load> mc1;
  std::cout << "mc1: " << mc1.show() << '\n';
  const MyClass<double, DriverY, Unload> mc2;
  std::cout << "mc2: " << mc2.show() << '\n';

  std::cout << "\n~~~~ many types ~~~~\n";
  for(const auto &real: {"float", "double", "int"})
  {
    for(const auto &driver: {"driver-x", "driver-y", "driver-z"})
    {
      for(const auto &action: {"load", "unload", "sleep"})
      {
        try
        {
          with_MyClass(real, driver, action,
            [&](const auto &mc)
            {
              std::cout << "working with: " << mc.show() << '\n';
            });
        }
        catch(const std::exception &e)
        {
          std::cerr << "!!! " << e.what() << " !!!\n";
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if(argc>3)
  {
    std::cout << "\n~~~~ from command line ~~~~\n";
    try
    {
      with_MyClass(argv[1], argv[2], argv[3],
        [&](const auto &mc)
        {
          std::cout << "working with: " << mc.show() << '\n';
        });
    }
    catch(const std::exception &e)
    {
      std::cerr << "!!! " << e.what() << " !!!\n";
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```